# How to remove items from list conditionally

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
bigdumblist = [
    (0, 0, {'product_id': 2, 'product_uom_qty': 90}),
    (0, 0, {'product_id': 3, 'product_uom_qty': 5}),
    (0, 0, {'product_id': 5, 'product_uom_qty': 69})
]
```

I want to remove all items from the list where `'product_id'` is not 2 or 3, like so:

```
[
   (0, 0, {'product_id': 2, 'product_uom_qty': 90}),
   (0, 0, {'product_id': 3, 'product_uom_qty': 5})
]
```

What I have tried:

```
def not_in(item):
    if item["product_id"] is not 2 or 3:
        bigdumblist.remove((0, 0, {'product_id': 5, 'product_uom_qty': 69}))

for _, _, item in bigdumblist:
    not_in(item)
    break

print(bigdumblist)
```

Which works but obviously including `(0, 0, {'product_id': 5, 'product_uom_qty': 69})` is not a solution. How can I properly remove specific items in the list?

Comment: You shouldn't modify a list while you're iterating over it.

Comment: `if item["product_id"] not in (2, 3):`

Comment: Not opposed to making a new list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension like so:

```
[x for x in bigdumblist if x[2]['product_id'] in [2,3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't modify a list while you're iterating over it. You could make a copy of the list first, but it's simpler to use a list comprehension.

Since the list comprehension specifies which elements to keep rather than delete, the condition must be inverted.

```
bigdumblist = [item for item in bigdumblist if item[2]['product_id'] in (2, 3)]
```

Note that

```
if item["product_id"] is not 2 or 3:
```

is parsed as if it were

```
if (item["product_id"] is not 2) or 3:
```

Since `3` is always truthy, this condition will always succeed. Logical operators like `and` and `or` are not automatically distributed over relational operators.

Answer (score 0):

Try a conditional list comprehension like this....

[x for x in bigdumblist if x[2]['product_id'] in [2,3]]

Answer (score 0):

You should really use list comprehension for that kind of filter, something like this:

```
bigdumblist = [
    (0, 0, {'product_id': 2, 'product_uom_qty': 90}),
    (0, 0, {'product_id': 3, 'product_uom_qty': 5}),
    (0, 0, {'product_id': 5, 'product_uom_qty': 69})
]

newlist = [i for i in bigdumblist if i[2]['product_id'] not in [2,3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension is one way to do this.

You probably want something similar to:

```
filtered_list = [item for item in original_list if item["product_id"] in (2, 3)]
```

Another option is [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter):

```
def valid_products(item):
    return item["product_id"] in (2,3)

filtered_list = list(filter(valid_products, original_list))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
items = [item for item in bigdumblist if item item[2]['product_id'] in (2,3)]
```